# How to escape left double quotes and right double quotes?

Tags: bash, mv, escape-characters

I want to change name with **mv** command. The file is inside left and right double quotes. e.g

**“My file name.”** want to change it to  **My_file_name**

How can can I can escape the special character **“** and **”**. I know about regular double quotes **"** but somehow cannot find a way to escape the special double quotes.

The way I change the name for now, is with graphical file manager nautilus. I use gnome terminal as terminal emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, left and right double quotes aren't special for bash, so they won't act like normal double quotes `"`. They don't need to be escaped.

Try surrounding everything with single quotes `' '` as it makes all the content literal.

You issue is probably the spaces in the name, not the quotes.

Comment: Thanks. That was the solution. Now I need to find how to write the left double quote “ character lol

Comment: You can use wildcards, @llesh

Comment: You can use kcharselect to get any special character into your clipboard. @llesh

Answer (score 0):

`ls *'My file name'* | od -t x1o1ac` should show you the filename bytes in hex, octal, ascii name and C notation.

I suspect your quotes are LEFT (and RIGHT) DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, multibyte in UTF-8 encoding.

You can input arbitrary octal with the `$'...'` Bash string.

```
$ echo $'\342\200\234 \342\200\235'
“ ”
$ echo $'\342\200\234 \342\200\235' | od -t x1o1ac
0000000  e2  80  9c  20  e2  80  9d  0a
        342 200 234 040 342 200 235 012
          b nul  fs  sp   b nul  gs  nl
        342 200 234     342 200 235  \n
0000010
```